# Detecting distortion from live guitar

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to detect if a guitar is being distorted. The sound of the guitar is being read in via a microphone. I am using p5 sound and there is a distortion class but I am unsure of how to use it. If anyone has any suggestions about other libraries that may be able to do this that would be great.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The [distortion class](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Distortion) is for *adding* distortion to sounds, not for *detecting* it. You could perhaps try using the [FFT class](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.FFT) to look for characteristic frequency patterns. However, I think your question is probably too broad for StackOverflow. Asking for help finding code libraries is definitely off-topic.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the advice all the same! I'll give that FFT idea a go!

Comment: Yes, do. And come back if there are any specific problems you need help with. Sounds like an interesting challenge. Have fun with it :)